# Is there a way to specify which sub-folders should display differently from Windows 7's default view?

Tags: windows, thumbnails, default-settings

First, I want to leave my default settings to "detailed" view since most of the time I prefer to have a quick glance at the `size`, `date created`, `type` columns.

[image: Example of "detailed" view]

But is there a way to override Windows' default folder display setting so only a few **selected** sub-folders use the "thumbnail" view instead?

[image: Example of "thumbnail" view]

By **"selected"**, what I mean is ideally this could be by a "regular expression" test against the sub-folder path. Where would this go though.... I'm not sure. If some sort of hidden/system file extension can be used in the folder hierarchy to indicate this, that'd be great!

Or maybe a small program or few lines in a batch file can alter this setting recursively when it finds a matching sub-folder (by starting off in a given root folder, in my case pretty much my entire client's projects folder).

Is this something feasible at all so I don't have to manually switch views with the dropdown thumbnail-vs-lists icon? (or whatever it's called)

## EDIT

The point of this is so that when I'm editing images in Photoshop and using "Save for Web...", I can quickly glance and see which image I need to update, instead of remembering which filename it is (*which is often time buried under 2 Photoshop modal windows above the opened PSD documents*).
[image]

So actually, if there's a way to use thumbnails ONLY when using this specific dialog box, that would be a solution as well I suppose (except, every folder I would browse to would generate thumbnails... so... not such a great idea).

Comment: I'm also trying to avoid having to "Right-Click -> Preview" the files individually, essentially *guessing* which one it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder or folders, select Customize tab and select Optimize this folder for.

You can select Images and if you want all subfolders to take this behavior check the option *Also apply this template to all subfolders*

Comment: Sounds like this would have to be done for each individual folder, instead of setting a rule once to enforce the thumbnail view on existing AND newly created folders...